# nodejs child_process pass cmd args down to script

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I use child_process.spawn to create a new process:

`child_process.spawn('node', ['app.js', 'x']);`

is there a way for me to get the cmd args(`['app.js', 'x']`) in app.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access this in the usual way (the global [process API](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)) by accessing `process.argv` or `process.execArgv` within *app.js*

Comment: that's right. Btw, any reference for the options(the third param)? `child_process.spawn('node', ['app.js', 'x'], {option goes here});`

Comment: Node.js official documentation is a good start (albeit not always satisfactory): https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options